# can't access different text files in python

Tags: python, file-io, file-handling

```
def input_files(file):
    s=0
    #word=raw_input('enter the word you want to search\n')
    file=file.readlines()
    for lines in file:
        if word in lines:
            s+=lines.count(word)
    print s
word=raw_input('enter the word you want to search\n')
file =open("2.txt")
file2=open("3.txt")
input_files(file)
input_files(file2)
```

This is the code of what i am doing and now i get the result which i want,but now i want to make my code mature.I don't want to call method again and again for reading text files,for example if i have 39 text files of dataset so i have to call function 39 TIMES this is more than enough so if anybody know the way through which i don't have to call the method again and again it just automatically get the text files and show their output and rank them according to the result which file have more word.

Comment: i think this is not possible through loops.

Comment: remove `file=file.readlines`. A file is an iterator over lines in Python

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to read this documentation for sys.argv `http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html` it help you in understanding this lib and through this lib you can access different text files in directory. `sys.argv[1:]` [1:] is the arguments, it's better not to start it from zero. `http://www.ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/sys-module.html` this is more clear and better and also focus on your coding

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a loop:

import sys

```
def input_files(fd, word):
    """return the occurences of `word` in a file"""
    s = 0
    for lines in fd:
        if word in lines:
            s += lines.count(word)
    return s


if __name__ == '__main__':
    word = raw_input('Enter the word you want to search: ')
    total = 0

    for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
        try:
            print("Searching for %s in %s..." % (word, filename))
            with open(filename, "r") as fd:
                found = input_files(fd, word)
                total += found
                print("\t... found %i occurence(s)\n" % found)
        except IOError:
            print("\t... cannot open %s !" % filename)

    print("\nTotal: %i occurences" % total)
```

It will process all the files passed as arguments to your script...

---

#### Explanations:

`sys.argv` is the variable containing the arguments passed to a script *via* the command line.

For instance, if you execute the command `python my_script.py foo bar` the `sys.argv` variable in `my_script.py` will contain `["my_script.py", "foo", "bar"]`.

As you can see, the first element of `sys.argv` is the name of the script itself, so we have to skip it (`sys.argv[1:]` means *« all items of `sys.argv` starting from index 1 »*, the item 0 is skipped).

So in the script above, all the files passed as arguments to the script will be processed. 
Of course, if one of the file doesn't exists, it will fail.

Sources

- [sys.argv](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.argv#sys.argv)
- [sequence types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq)

Comment: can you please tell me about sys.argy[1:] i dnt have any idea about it

Comment: but this is not opening my file !! no output

Comment: It's opening the files you pass as arguments, i've just tested. But what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: maybe add a `raw_input()` in the code, so it matches original code; while at it, maybe include all code, instead of just the `for` loop

Comment: import re
   import sys
def input_files(file):
    s=0
    #word=raw_input('enter the word you want to search\n')
    #file=file.readlines()
    for lines in file:
        if word in lines:
            s+=lines.count(word)
    print s
word=raw_input('enter the word you want to search\n')
#file =open("2.txt")
"""file2=open("3.txt")
input_files(file)
input_files(file2)"""
for file in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(file,"r") as fd:
        input_files("2.txt","3.txt")

Comment: Your code is almost unreadable because Stackoverflow shown it on one line, but is seems your called your `input_files` function with an `str` as argument instead of a file object, that's probably why it doesn't works. @Tshepang: yeah, i will write the complete code and improve it a bit...

Comment: my concentaration in only on UNI gram , till now i have no concern with bi gram my focus in just on calling method through loop or anything better !

Comment: note that the other did not a notification for your message: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/; one solution is, next time, just write separate messages for each recipient

Answer (score 2):

Your code is slightly wrong, since it counts sub-words as occurrences of words. For example "This is a bad test".count('a') will give 2 rather than 1.

Word-splitting correctly is a bit tricky, but here's a simple start that breaks words at punctuation or spaces.

```
def input_files(f, word):
    print sum(re.split('[ .,;:"]').count(word) for line in f)
```

A good alternative would be to use a regular expression to find occurrences of the word (although I think this makes things slightly harder).

This code has a few other improvements over your version: if you use a file object as an iterator, you get lines without having to do an explicit `readlines()` (this avoids reading the entire file into RAM and representing it as a list), and when you say `if word in line: s += line.count(word)` you're actually making things slower than if you just write `s += line.count(word)` since it requires 2 scans over the line rather than just one.

I've also passed the word you're scanning for into the function, because it makes the code more obvious (and you could even write unit tests for this version).

To continue... rather than printing the word-count out, you probably want to return it (since you want to find the files with the greatest word-count). Then you can count the occurrences of the given word per file, and sort them.

Here's a solution, that uses command-line arguments and that doesn't have any error-checking.
Usage: [program] word file1 file2...

```
import sys

def words_in_file(filename, word):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return sum(re.split('[ .,;:"]', line).count(word) for line in f)

def files_by_wordcount(filenames, word):
    counts = [(words_in_file(filename, word), filename) for filename in filenames]
    return sorted(counts, reverse=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for count, filename in files_by_wordcount(sys.argv[2:], sys.argv[1]):
        print filename, count
```

Comment: +1 : I haven't noticed the code was counting the sub-words :-)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but i am new in python how i create the file object as the last answer also ask me to use file object as argument

Comment: my concentaration in only on UNI gram , till now i have no concern with bi gram

Comment: @munieb You can create a file object by calling the `open` function: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects

Comment: Your word-splitting line won't work.  `line.split(' .,;:"')` doesn't split on any of the characters in passed, it splits on the *string* which is passed, which (hopefully!) doesn't exist in the string.

Comment: still still it doesn't pick/access my text files through sys.argv[]